# Como recorrer datagrid para formar un correo con los datos del mismo y remover unas columnas? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, datagrid

Estoy recorriendo un datagrid en vb.net y con la información que tiene formo un correo en formato html para enviarlo por correo, todo funciona bien, solo que el datagrid tiene dos columnas que estan marcadas en la foto que estan con la propiedad invisible y las cuales cuando recorro el datagrid también aparecen en el correo, otra también es la última columna no quiero que salga en el correo, como se le haría para excluir esas columnas y la última a la hora de recorrer el datagrid?

foto:
[image: Imagen del datagrid]

Codigo con el cual recorro el datagrid y formo una tabla en formato html el cual es enviado por correo.

```
 Dim BodyCorre As String
    BodyCorre = "<table width='80%' style='border:Solid 2px Black;' 
    bgcolor='#3366FF' ><tr><th>ACTIVIDAD</th><th>RESPONSABLE</th> 
   <th>ESTATUS</th><th></th><th></th><th>FCH. TERMINO</th><th></th></tr>"
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    BodyCorre += "<tr bgcolor=#c3cbcb>"
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In Row.Cells
    BodyCorre += "<td >" & cell.Value & "</td>
    Next
    Next
    BodyCorre += "</table>"
```

el correo que llega es el siguiente:
[image: Correo cuando llega]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es validar los indices de las celdas que no quieres que se agreguen, algo asi:

```
   Dim BodyCorre As String
    BodyCorre = "<table width='80%' style='border:Solid 2px Black;' bgcolor='#3366FF'><tr><th>ACTIVIDAD</th><th>RESPONSABLE</th><th>ESTATUS</th><th></th><th></th><th>FCH. TERMINO</th><th></th></tr>"
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        BodyCorre = String.Format("{0}<tr bgcolor=#c3cbcb>", BodyCorre)
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In Row.Cells


            If Convert.ToString(Row.Cells(1).Value) <> Convert.ToString(cell.Value) And Convert.ToString(Row.Cells(2).Value) <> Convert.ToString(cell.Value) And Convert.ToString(Row.Cells(6).Value) <> Convert.ToString(cell.Value) Then
                BodyCorre = String.Format("{0}<td>{1}</td>", BodyCorre, cell.Value)
            End If


        Next
    Next

    BodyCorre = String.Format("{0} </table>", BodyCorre)
```

En el if indicas que mientras el valor de la celda que estas recorriendo en el foreach sea diferente al valor de la celda con el indice especifico que no quieres tomar en cuenta lo concatene a tu variable para construir la tabla